# PXE booting from AWS EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I am working to create a cloud managed provisioning system to be used with a number of computers located on home networks. As part of this, I would really like to setup a PXE server on AWS that can be booted on demand if a computer goes down.

Does PXE booting only work from the local network, or is there some way to specify the location of the server (from the local home router)? I would like to avoid use of a VPN as network bandwidth is a concern for normal operation of the machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [iPXE](http://ipxe.org) to accomplish this by hard coding a URL to boot from. You'd likely have to `chainload` to do this which is well documented at the site.